# Why no perfect participle? "Sie hat sich scheiden lassen"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitive, past-participle, auxiliary-verb

> Sie hat sich gestern von ihm scheiden lassen.

This sentence uses the infinitive *lassen* instead of the perfect participle *gelassen*. Which grammatical rule causes this?

Comment: Have also a look at [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5187/1224) and the [helpful link to canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882) that is introduced in that question

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the so-called [*Ersatzinfinitiv*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv). It is used with the following verbs:

- lassen — *Sie haben sich scheiden lassen.*
- müssen — *Er hat sie nehmen müssen.*
- können — *Ich habe ihn treffen können.*
- dürfen — *Sie hat ihn küssen dürfen.*
- wollen — *Wir haben Dich sehen wollen.*
- sollen — *Ich habe ihn pflegen sollen.*
- mögen — *Sie hat mich nicht sehen mögen.*
- brauchen — *Er hat mich nicht rufen brauchen.*
- hören — *Wir haben ihn atmen hören.*
- sehen — *Das habe ich kommen sehen.*
- heißen — *Wir haben ihn gehen heißen.* (= *Wir haben ihn aufgefordert, zu gehen.* This usage of *heißen* is mostly obsolete.)

Depending on the dialect, *fühlen* and *helfen* can be added to the list.

For details, check out e.g. [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/0,1518,632042,00.html):

> Normalerweise wird das Perfekt immer mit einer Form von *haben* oder *sein* plus dem Perfektpartizip gebildet [...] **Hängt vom Verb aber eine Infinitivkonstruktion ab,** wenn es also nicht bloß *Ich höre dich* heißt, sondern *Ich höre dich atmen*, **dann tritt im Perfekt anstelle des Partizips (*gehört*) eine zweite Grundform auf, ein sogenannter Ersatzinfinitiv**: *Ich habe dich atmen hören*.

And further:

> Bei Verben der Wahrnehmung wie "sehen" und "hören" sind indes beide Formen möglich, was wohl auch der Grund für die gelegentliche Verunsicherung ist. Und auch bei "lassen" bleiben wir ganz gelassen und lassen uns beide Paar Schuhe passen. **Den Beispielsatz "Die Partei hat den Kandidaten fallen lassen" gibt es auch in der Variante "Die Partei hat den Kandidaten fallen gelassen". Beides gilt als korrekt.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Wir haben ihn willkommen geheißen`?

Comment: @swegi: Why? This question regards why it should _not_.

Comment: @Tim: It just sounds more correct to me.

Comment: There is also a [grammIS article](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=11&v_id=99) about the Ersatzinfinitiv.

Comment: @swegi is absolutely right, because _willkommen_ is no verb. I’ve edited the answer to give a correct example (but _jemanden etwas tun heißen_ is obsolete anyway).

Comment: In my opinion, "worden" is missing in that list...

Comment: @Emanuel: _Er ist dabei sehen worden_?

Comment: @chirlu: good point. However, I think the Ersatzinfinitiv is independent of whether it's complement contains a real infinite or a participle... I might be wrong though

Comment: Note that this corner of the language is tricky even for native German speakers. Sometimes the choice between past participle and Ersatzinfinitiv can express nuances that not every native speaker will be fully aware of: "Ich habe den Tsunami kommen gesehen." (I watched as the tsunami came.) "Ich habe den Tsunammi kommen sehen." (I anticipated the tsunami.)

Comment: FALSCH!!! Diese Antwort geht an der Frage vorbei! Der Ersatzinfinitiv kommt in diesem Satz vor: *»Sie hat den Schlüssel liegen **lassen**«* (sie hat etwas unverändert gelassen) aber nicht in *»Sie hat sich scheiden **lassen**«* (Sie hat etwas initiiert). Das ist eine ganz ander Bedeutung von *lassen*! Jemanden dazu bringen etwas zu tun: »Ich habe ihn den Tisch decken lassen.« Etwas so lassen wie es war: »Ich habe den Tisch gedeckt lassen.« Nur wenn etwas belassen wird, handelt es sich um einen Ersatzinfinitiv, und das ist im nachgefragten Satz nicht der Fall.

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be always the case when the supposed participle (e.g. *lassen*) goes with an infinitive (e.g. *scheiden*).

> Ich kann fliehen. Ich habe fliehen können.
>
> Ich kann nichts. Ich habe nichts gekonnt.

Most of the concerned verbs are "Modalverben" in German and follow this rule (have a look at [mein-deutschbuch.de](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=107#perfektmodal)).

So, you might say that *lassen* is used as a "Modalverb" here.

Here a very common example from a children's rhyme:

> Susi hat sich küssen lassen. (Susi let herself be kissed.)

Now, I finally understand that the point of this rhyme is practicing this exception.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any other words except for modal verbs and _lassen_ that behave like this? Also: Is this _always_ the case with _lassen_ preceded by an infinitive?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, with the caveat that you might construct a sequence where "lassen" is preceded by an infinitive that grammatically belongs to a subphrase and not to "lassen".

Comment: Although this is true for standard German, there are quite some dialects where the perfect participle is commonly used to in those cases.

Comment: @Koraktor: Would you mind listing them? (Or should this be a new question?)

Answer (score -1):

It's a passive action, in German (as well as in English(?), you don't "divorce", you "get divorced".
"Sich scheiden lassen" is the action that belongs to "Die Scheidung".

Also, the word "hat" is the past tense form of "haben", so the past tense is already defined in that statement and "lassen" can and must stay in the infinitive form.

Comment: What is the difference between this sentence and "Sie hat sich gestern von ihm getrennt", where the past participle is used?

Comment: @Jesmus42 I don't think "hat" is always in the past tense.  It can be used for many tenses--your statement is somewhat misleading.

Comment: @Tim: "sich von jemandem trennen" is similiar to "sich scheiden lassen", but it does not equal "divorce", it's just "to break up". As far as grammar is concerned, thei's and RegDwight's answers are more accurate, sorry for that.

Comment: They're certainly different verbs. I was wondering why one uses the perfect participle while the other does not.

Comment: @Tim at this point it comes back to the passive/active concept. "Sich scheiden lassen" is a passive action, "sich trennen" is an active action, both rely on different rules when it comes to past tense.

Comment: "hat" cannot be a past form alone, it has to be followed by a participle construction (participle, or infinitive form vor modal verbs and some more). But the fact that it is a passive form (you "get a divorce recognized from the society" or whoever) is a very good point.

Comment: I think in English you can divorce someone, meaning that you get divorced from them.