# Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen »hätte machen sollen« and »sollte gemacht haben«

Tags: word-order, modal-verb, perfect-tense

Ich bin in der letzten Zeit einige Male korrigiert worden, als ich die zwei Verbformen im Titel benutzt habe. Deshalb vermute ich, dass es einen Bedeutungsunterschied gibt, den ich noch nicht verstanden habe.

Die Verbformen sind also wie folgt:

1. Hilfsverb + Infinitiv Vollverb + Infinitiv Modalverb
2. Präteritum Modalverb + Partizip II Vollverb + Hilfsverb

Beispiele:

1. > Das hat jeder mal machen sollen.
2. > Das sollte jeder mal gemacht haben.

Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den zwei Sätzchen, und wenn ja, welcher? (Für mich bedeuten die beiden: »Everyone should have done that at least once.«)

Die erste Verbform kann *Perfekt mit Modalverb* genannt werden. Wie nennt man die andere?

Comment: Sollte Satz 1 nicht heißen: 1. Das **hätte** jeder mal machen sollen ?

Comment: Ja, du hast wahrscheinlich recht. Die Sätze sind von mir konzipiert worden und können Fehler einhalten. Eine _Linguee.de_ -Suche für "hat machen sollen" hat nur Treffer für "hätte machen sollen". Ergibt überhaupt 'Das hat jeder mal machen sollen' sinn?

Comment: @Stovner: 'Das hat jeder mal machen sollen' würde im Kontext wahrscheinlich meistens verstanden, aber als seltsam klingend registriert.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following section taken from [Modern German Grammar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0415273005) really helped me with this distinction (please correct me if I'm not understanding your question properly). Since I really can't say it better myself, I will just quote:

> Two different patterns involving modal
>   verbs
>
> **muss/soll/kann (etc.) gewesen sein vs.
>   hätte sein müssen/sollen/können (etc.)**
>
> **muss/soll/kann (etc.) gesagt haben vs.
>   hätte sagen müssen/sollen/können
>   (etc.)**
>
> Note the existence of these different
>   patterns and their completely
>   different functions. They are a source
>   of difﬁculty because English speakers
>   often use the same construction ‘would
>   have’/‘could have’/‘must have’ etc.
>   for two distinct purposes: ‘He could
>   have gone to Oxford’, for example,
>   could mean ‘I think it is possible
>   that he did’ or ‘There was the
>   possibility, but it didn’t happen’. In
>   German these two meanings are
>   expressed using two different
>   structures.
>
> (a) The muss gewesen sein/muss gesagt
>   haben pattern expresses an assumption
>   or a deduction on the part of the
>   speaker about an event assumed to have
>   taken place in the past. The speaker
>   voices the possibility or the
>   probability that something really did
>   happen in a certain way. This pattern
>   basically follows this special use of
>   the future perfect for expressing
>   assumptions (e.g. wird gewesen
>   sein/wird gesagt haben), but uses a
>   modal verb instead of werden.
>
> The structure is as follows: Modal
>   verb (usually in the present tense) +
>   past participle of the main verb (e.g.
>   gewesen, gesagt) + haben or sein
>   depending on the main verb.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> *"Sie kann die Inhaberin des Hotels
>   gewesen sein."*
>
> She could have been the owner of the
>   hotel (I suppose).   (= It is possible
>   that she was the owner of the hotel.)
>
> *"Sie muss das gleich am Anfang gesagt
>   haben."*
>
> She must have said that right at the
>   outset (I suppose).   (= It must be
>   the case that she did so. That is what
>   I suppose/deduce/expect.)
>
> *"Er soll die Stelle bekommen haben."*
>
> He is believed to have got the
>   job./They say he got the job.
>
> (b) The hätte sein müssen/hätte sagen
>   müssen pattern expresses an unrealized
>   possibility attaching to an event in
>   the past. The speaker is effectively
>   asserting or implying that a
>   particular eventuality did not happen.
>
> The structure is as follows:
>   hätte/hättest/hätten/hättet +
>   inﬁnitive of the main verb + inﬁnitive
>   of the modal verb. Note that this
>   structure is actually the simpler of
>   the two, because it always uses a form
>   of hätte even when the main verb is
>   one that forms the perfect and
>   pluperfect tense with sein.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> *"Sie hätte die Inhaberin des Hotels
>   sein können."*
>
> She could have been the owner of the
>   hotel (but it didn’t happen).
>
> *"Sie hätte das gleich am Anfang sagen
>   müssen."*
>
> She would have had to say that right
>   at the outset (but she didn’t).
>
> *"Er hätte die Stelle bekommen sollen."*
>
> He ought to have got the job (but he
>   didn’t).

Comment: Thanks for the excellent reply and book recommendation. The excerpt is so good that I will try browsing through it in a bookstore and maybe buy it.

Comment: There's a new (2011) edition of [Modern German Grammar](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0415567262/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) available. (Or get the 2009 edition in Kindle format for only $14, vs $40 for the paperback! I may just buy it now... :))

Comment: Yup that book is pretty solid, if either of you decide to get it, I hope you find it as helpful as I do :)

Comment: I found an old first edition copy for $1.88 on half.com.  I don't care about the slight spelling changes after 1996.  I just want the grammar. ;)

Comment: @ghshtalt What's the difference between "Sie kann die Inhaberin des Hotels gewesen sein" AND "Sie kann die Inhaberin des Hotels sein" AND "Sie könnte die Inhaberin des Hotels sein"???

Answer (score 6):

Die Frage ist wirklich nicht sehr einfach.

Im ersten Beispielsatz steht das Modalverb `sollen` im sogenannten **Ersatzinfinitiv** für das Partizip Perfekt:

> Das hat jeder mal machen sollen.

In den zusammengesetzten Zeiten wird das Partizip Perfekt also durch den Infinitiv Präsens ersetzt, wenn es **unmittelbar nach einem Infinitiv** (im Beispiel: *machen*) steht. Dies geschieht zum Beispiel im Perfekt und Plusquamperfekt.

Inhaltlich bedeutet der Satz übrigens: *"Jeder hatte den **Auftrag** das zu machen."*

---

Der zweite Satz

> Das sollte jeder mal gemacht haben.

ist grammatikalisch Konjunktiv (*sollte*) + Futur II (*gemacht haben*)

Die Bedeutung des Satzes ist als **Empfehlung** zu sehen.

---

Die dritte Variante, die im Titel der Frage auftaucht:

> Das hätte jeder mal machen sollen.

Das ist eine **irreale Modalverbkonstruktion**; irreal deshalb, weil sich der Satz auf etwas in der Vergangenheit "Nicht-Geschehenes" bezieht, das geschehen hätte sollen. Deshalb wird der Konjunktiv II verwendet.

---

Abschließend sei zu erwähnen, dass auch Menschen deutscher Muttersprache Probleme haben, die erwähnten Satzkonstruktionen zu unterscheiden. Also: Lass(t) dich/euch beim Lernen nicht entmutigen!

Comment: +1 weil du wahrgenommen hast, dass es tatsächlich drei perfekten Vergangenheitsformen mit diesen drei Verben gibt, aber auch für die letzte Aufmunterung. :)

Answer (score 2):

Satz 1

> Als ich gestern im Sportunterricht war, hat jeder eine Rolle rückwärts machen sollen.

Das Ziel wurde von der Schule festgelegt, jedenfalls nicht vom Sprecher.

Satz 2

> Eine Weltreise sollte jeder mal gemacht haben.

Ich finde, dass das so sein soll, das Ziel geht von mir aus, also vom Sprecher

Answer (score 0):

Hilfsverb + Infinitiv Vollverb + Infinitiv Modalverb

Das hat jeder mal machen sollen.

A small detail, sorry for my poor English:
Even, in this case "sollen' has the same form as the infinitiv, it is a special form of Partizip II, which is used in combination with other verb, in this case "machen".

So the schema is:
Hilfsverb + Infinitiv Vollverb + Partizp II

The same in hätte machen sollen, again it is Partip II

The structure - schema is exactly the same

Präteritum Modalverb + Partizip II Vollverb + Hilfsverb

Partizip II + Hilfsverb = Infinitiv of past tense

you can simplify it to:

Präteritum Modalverb + Infinitiv of past tense ( gekommen sein, gesagt haben, gemacht haben )

Comment: Re: "a special form of Partizip II", the term you are looking for is [Ersatzinfinitiv](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-no-perfect-participle-sie-hat-sich-scheiden-lassen/111#111).

Comment: IThis term is wrong, as I explaned above. It is not an infinitiv.

Comment: You didn't explain it. You just said that it isn't an infinitive. I am merely supplying the actual term used by linguists. Do note the *Ersatz-* part.

Comment: *Ersatzinfinitiv* is definitively right. Normally you're supposed to use the Partizip Perfekt, but you have to use this special infinitive for modal verbs.

Comment: I know to form it 20 years. The user had used the term "infinitiv", this is to what I refered in my note. And however it is mostly called, "Ersatzinfinitiv" it is worng. It should be called Ersatzpartizip, because it is not an infinitiv. I hope I explaned now, with my poor English, what I mean.

Comment: "Do note the Ersatz- part".
Ersatzmutter, ersetzt die biologische Mutter, Ersatzinfinitiv sollte also logischerweise den Infinitiv ersetzen, was er klarerweise nicht tut. Das war mein Punkt, nichts mehr, nichts weniger.