# What grammar form is "Es muss gemacht worden sein"?

Tags: grammar, passive

I thought the following sentence was *Perfekt Passive mit Modalverb (PPmMV)*:

> Es muss gemacht worden sein.

But I just found a book which says that "PPmMV" is:

> Es hat gemacht werden müssen.

So what grammar form is "Es muss gemacht worden sein" (if this is correct at all)?

Comment: Both sentences are grammatical, but they mean completely different things. ("I guess it's been done" vs. "It had to be done".)

Comment: A related question, but without the passive: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/799/119

Comment: 1st sentence: It must have been made. 2nd sentence: It had to be done.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I would say both are *Perfekt Passiv mit Modalverb*.

So, that's a little bit tricky to explain. Short version: One sentence uses the perfect of "müssen", the other the perfect of "werden".

Both sentences use the *Modalverb* "müssen".

Both sentences use the auxiliary verb "werden" to build the passive.

*Präsens* of the first sentence:

> Es muss gemacht werden.

The [perfect of "werden"](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/perfekt.html) is composed with "sein".

The *Partizip II* of the auxiliary verb "werden" is "[worden](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/worden)". (Be aware: The *Partizip II* of the normal verb "werden" ist "geworden".)

So with the *Perfekt* of "werden" we get:

> Es muss gemacht worden sein.

*Präsens* of your second sentence:

> Es muss gemacht werden. (same as above)

The [perfect of "müssen"](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/perfekt.html) is composed with "haben".

The *Partizip II* of the verb "müssen" is "gemusst". The *Partizip II* of the *Modalverb* "müssen" is in this case "müssen". (I show you why.)

So we would get for the *Perfekt* of müssen:

> Es hat gemacht werden gemusst. (This is wrong!)

"gemusst" stands behind the infinitive of "werden", so it is [changed to "müssen"](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-V/Texte/PerfModal1.html). Your sentence with the *Perfekt* of "müssen":

> Es hat gemacht werden müssen. (This is correct)

I hope this was not too discouraging. And I hope I haven't introduced too many errors in my explanation, because this twisted my mind a little bit till I figured it out. Sometimes being a native speaker is a curse ;)

Answer (score 6):

You're right. The form

> Es muss gemacht worden sein

is perfekt passive with a modal verb (*müssen*). In this case the subjective modal verb *müssen* is used to express an assumption.

The active form would be (for your example):

> Er/Sie muss es gemacht haben.

Answer (score 1):

*Es hat gemacht werden müssen*. (Objective meaning: It had to be done.)
*Es muss gemacht worden sein*. (Subjective meaning which used to express guessing sth.  when someone is very sure: It must have been done.)

If the modal verb stands in front, the meaning is subjective. For example:
Es kann gemacht worden sein. (It could have been done) implies that someone is 50 % sure.

Answer (score -1):

"Es muss" is *Präsens* (present), "gemacht worden sein" is, as far as I know, an adverb ("gemacht worden sein müssen").

Comment: "gemacht worden sein" is indicative perfect passive, exactly what OP thought.

Comment: I kind of agree that it is basically present. The sentence is the same construction as :   "Das Auto muss blau sein." That is clearly present.    The only difference is that instead of "blau" the characteristic here is expressed using a particip passive. However, the actual action here "müssen", be it as assumption or not, is in present. I think, naming it differently can lead to a lot of confusion.    "Ich will einen Kaffee getrunken haben." is also present. I want it NOW. Not in past, not in future. And these forms do exist too...

Comment: Es hätte gemacht worden sein müssen would be double past, if we had to name it in line with the way the other answers propose... Past-conditional-modal-past-perfect... kind of over the top, IMHO :)