# Wie übersetzt man "It could have happened" am besten ins Deutsche?

Tags: translation

Eine kurze Recherche im Internet ergibt, dass anscheinend meistens eine Konstruktion mit *hätte können* (also Konjunktiv II) verwendet wird. Könnte man hier auch *könnte passiert sein* verwenden? Ich kann keinen Unterschied erkennen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide von Deinen Übersetzungen gehen, die Bedeutungen sind aber anders.

> Es hätte passieren können.

Ein Ereignis hätte passieren können, wenn eine Vorbedingung erfüllt worden wäre. Da die Vorbedingung *in Wirklichkeit* nicht erfüllt worden ist, ist das Ereignis nicht passiert. Man weiß schon, dass das Ereignis **nicht** passiert ist.

> Es könnte passiert sein.

Man weiß nicht, ob ein Ereignis passiert ist oder nicht. Man spekuliert nur, dass es **vielleicht** passiert ist.

Die beiden Fälle drückt man im Englischen in der Tat mit "It could have happened" aus.

Siehe auch [meine Frage hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/translation-of-it-could-have-worked).

Comment: Also related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/799/bedeutungsunterschied-zwischen-h%C3%A4tte-machen-sollen-and-sollte-gemacht-haben?rq=1