# How would "He could have seen me" be translated to German?

Tags: subjunctive

Which of these two are the correct translation of the sentence "He could have seen me"?

> 1. Er könnte mich gesehen haben.
> 2. Er hätte mich gesehen können.

I have seen both forms and am a little confused. If both are correct please tell me where to use which one if there's a preference.

Best,
Hooman

Comment: Related: [Translation of “It could have worked”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18256/translation-of-it-could-have-worked)

Comment: Related: [Wie übersetzt man “It could have happened” am besten ins Deutsche?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18479/wie-%C3%BCbersetzt-man-it-could-have-happened-am-besten-ins-deutsche)

Comment: Thanks Loong. I saw these links and they both were pretty helpful. They both confirmed the below response by Stephie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He could have seen me.

translates to:

> Er hätte mich sehen können.

Your use of conditional /"Konjunktiv" in you second suggestion was good, but you need the infinitive here ( no *"ge-"*).

---

Your first suggestion

> Er könnte mich gesehen haben.

Would translate back as

> He *might* have seen me.

Comment: Hello Stephie,
Thanks for correcting me on (2), and for your helpful reply. I got my answer, however it raises more questions for me :D
How would then these two sentences be different?
1. Er müsste mich gesehen haben.
2. Er Hätte mich sehen müssen.

Best,

Comment: Did you check the two related questions @Loong posted below your original question?

Comment: Yes Stephie. They both gave the same answer as you did.

Comment: Then you were able to answer your second question yourself? If not, please ask questions only in the questions section, unless it's a request for clarification.

Comment: My second question remains unresolved. I will ask it in the questions section.