# Warum Infinitiv anstatt Partizip-Perfekt? ("Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen gehört" vs "Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen hören")

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-tense, infinitive, past-participle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why no perfect participle? “Sie hat sich scheiden lassen”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-no-perfect-participle-sie-hat-sich-scheiden-lassen)

Die folgende Frage kommt von dem Einstufungstest des Goethe Instituts. Die richtige Antwort ist a) aber ich habe c) gewählt. Ich verstehe hier die Grammatik gar nicht. Könnt irgendjemand von euch es mir erklären?

> Ich habe dich gar nicht __
>
> a) kommen hören
> b) gekommen hören
> c) kommen gehört
> d) zu kommen gehört

Ich spreche Englisch als Muttersprachler und man sagt: *I did not hear you coming*. Man sagt das immer in der Vergangenheit. Aber auf Deutsch ist es nicht im Perfekt, weil dann wäre es *gehört*. Ich lerne Deutsch seit einer langen Zeit, aber manchmal kommen immer noch Sachen vor, von denen ich keine Ahnung habe.

Comment: Side note: If you leave out the action it would be correct to say "Ich habe dich gar nicht gehört".

Comment: And as a native German I'd admit that "kommen gehört" sounds better to me than "kommen hören" right now. Omg, how is it called if you lose all the feel for a language or a word sounds foreign to you, if you repeat a thing too often :D

Comment: Das habe ich [kommen sehen](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html) ;P

Comment: [Verben mit Infinitiv ohne zu](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/spezielle-verben/verben-ohne-zu/).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Du hast ein sehr schönes Beispiel, um die Unsinnigkeit dieser Tests (gerade des Goetheinstituts) zu zeigen. Bitte lass dich nicht durch Derartiges beirren, denn die meisten Muttersprachler hätten diese Frage genauso wie du beantwortet.

Nicht nur, dass der Satz "Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen gehört" zeitgemäßer klingt, laut [Duden](https://web.archive.org/web/20191009011602/https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hoeren) ist es eine korrekte Form. Schau im Link unter *Bedeutungen, Beispiele und Wendungen* nach.

Wenn ich die beiden Möglichkeiten "..dich kommen gehört" und "..dich kommen hören" vergleichen müsste, dann würde ich behaupten, dass Letzteres etwas literarischer und gehobener klingt, wohingegen Ersteres in der Umgangssprache oft anzutreffen ist.

Den grammatikalischen Hintergrund kann man in dem von Takkat geposteten Link zum Thema Ersatzinfinitiv nachlesen:

> Bei einigen Verben wird das Partizip Perfekt in den zusammengesetzten Zeiten durch den Infinitiv Präsens ersetzt, wenn es unmittelbar nach einem Infinitiv steht:
>
> Ich habe **weggehen dürfen**. (nicht: weggehen gedurft)

Dies ist stets die Regeln bei den Modalverben *dürfen*, *können*, *mögen*, *müssen*, *sollen* und *brauchen*, häufig bei den Verben *heißen*, *lassen*, *sehen* und manchmal auch bei *fühlen*, *helfen* und eben auch **hören**.

> Habt ihr uns **kommen hören**? (auch: **kommen gehört**)

Comment: halirutan, mit deiner Antwort ist leider nicht gesagt, warum es "hören" anstatt "gehört" sein soll. Was du nur erklärst, warum da "kommen" richtig ist. OP's Beispiel also: "Ich höre dich gar nicht kommen." Und jetzt die "deutsche Vergangenheit": "Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen gehört" oder halt, vllt doch "Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen hören". You know what I mean?

Comment: @Em1, hui, ich sehe es gerade.

Comment: Oder mit anderen Worten (damit es auch potentiellen zukünftigen Lesern, denen die Bedeutung meines Kommentars nicht direkt offensichtlich ist, klar ist, worauf ich hinaus will): "Ich höre Peter. Er kommt." Hier kann man - aufgrund der von dir genannten Regeln - *Er kommt* durch den Infinitiv substituieren -> "Ich höre Peter kommen". Nun versuch das mal mit "Ich rauche eine Zigarette. Sie glimmt." -> "Ich rauche eine Zigarette glimmen"??? Geht nicht. - Aber das war ja hier nicht die Frage... Aber das hast du ja jetzt auch schon erkannt :)

Comment: Der gepostete Link hat mir wirklich geholfen. Vielen Dank hailrutan. Der Schlüsselbegriff ist "Ersatzinfinitiv". Ich hab mal gegooglt. Die Wikipedia Seite ist auch sehr hilfreich http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv

Comment: Die Behauptung im zweiten Satz ist unbelegt.