# Wie sagt man "You should not have gone to work" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

Im Moment versuche ich einer Freundin eine SMS zu schicken. Ich habe es gerade geschrieben, aber es ist mir aufgefallen, dass ich nicht weiß wie man "You should not have gone to work" auf Deutsch sagt.

Ich sehe 2 Möglichkeiten aber ich bin der Ansicht, dass beide ein bisschen komisch klingen. Kann man sagen?

> 1. Du solltest nicht in die Arbeit gegangen sein.
> 2. Du hättest nicht in die Arbeit gegangen sein sollen.

Comment: Auch *Du solltest (doch) nicht zur Arbeit gehen.* ist grammatikalisch richtiges Deutsch und wird auch häufig so gesagt. Der Unterschied liegt darin, was du hervorheben möchtest. Meines Erachtens ist *hätte nicht sollen* eine stärkere Betonung auf ein *Fehlverhalten* als nur *sollte nicht*.

Comment: @Em1: Doesn’t _Du solltest nicht gehen_ translate as _You should not go_? That has a different meaning from _You should not have gone_. (With the former, you haven’t yet gone and the advice is that it will be better if you don’t; with the latter, you did go but it would have been better if you hadn’t.)

Comment: @BrianNixon: No, that would have been _Du sollst nicht zur Arbeit gehen._ _Solltest_ in Em1's comment is past tense.

Comment: @mthomas: Good point; I was thinking that _Du sollst nicht gehen_ would translate as _You shall not go_.  But _sollst_ and _solltest_ don’t directly correspond to the English _shall_ and _should_.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Richtig ist:

> Du hättest nicht zur Arbeit gehen sollen.

"Hättest" zeigt hier bereits die Vergangenheit an.

Comment: Haben sie mehr Info? Warum benutzen wir zwei mal das Infinitiv. Gehen und Sollen? Wann darf man so was machen?

Comment: @VaccinalBowl [Warum Infinitiv anstatt Partizip-Perfekt?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5187/1224) - [Why no perfect participle?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/70/1224) - [Ersatzinfinitiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ersatzinfinitiv)

Answer (score 11):

Lassen wir mal das "nicht" weg. Diese Verneinung saugt nur unnötig Aufmerksamkeit vom eigentlichen Thema ab. Und aus "zur Arbeit" mache ich "fort", das vereinfacht den Satz auch ein wenig.

Eine einfache Beschreibung, Gegenwart:

> Du gehst fort.

Eine Vorhersage über ein Ereignis, das mit Sicherheit in der Zukunft stattfinden wird:

> Du wirst *fortgehen*.

Eine Aufforderung, ausgesprochen in der Gegenwart, um eine Handlung in der Zukunft auszulösen:

> Du sollst *fortgehen*.

Eine Beschwerde, ausgesprochen in der Gegenwart, wegen einer Handlung, die in der Vergangenheit nicht stattgefunden hat:

> Du hättest *fortgehen* sollen.

Das Schema für diese Konstruktion ist dieses:

> Du hättest [...] sollen.

Das, was da anstelle von [...] reinkommt, ist genau das, was im Futur-Satz nach "Du wirst" kommt:

> Du wirst *am Sonntag in die Kirche gehen*.
> Du hättest *am Sonntag in die Kirche gehen* sollen.
>
> Du wirst *ein siebengängiges Menü zubereiten*.
> Du hättest *ein siebengängiges Menü zubereiten* sollen.
>
> Du wirst *ein Buch über das Leben des Königs schreiben*.
> Du hättest *ein Buch über das Leben des Königs schreiben* sollen.
>
> Du wirst *nicht zur Arbeit gehen*.
> Du hättest *nicht zur Arbeit gehen* sollen.