# Wie konjugiert man "etwas sein lassen"?

Tags: grammar, verb, colloquial, inflection

Könnte mir jemand sagen, warum in einem deutschen Lehrbuch steht:

> Ich habe das sein **gelassen**.

Aber ich glaube es muss heißen:

> Ich habe das sein **lassen**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Beides ist nicht falsch. Die Version mit *lassen* verwendet den sogenannten Ersatzinfinitiv; bei manchen Verben, insbesondere den Modalverben wie *müssen*, ist der Ersatzinfinitiv zwingend, bei manchen anderen Verben kann man ihn verwenden oder auch nicht.

Weitere Details findet man [bei Canoo](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Finit-Infinit/Part2.html#Anchor-Ersatzinfinitiv-35882). Das Thema Ersatzinfinitiv wurde auch schon in diesen Fragen behandelt: [Why no perfect participle? "Sie hat sich scheiden lassen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70), [Warum Infinitiv anstatt Partizip-Perfekt? ("Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen gehört" vs "Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen hören")](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5187)

Comment: Ist dieser Satz richtig? Ich habe das sein lassen müssen? Vielen Dank für die schnelle Antwort.

Comment: @williclarkam: Ja, ist richtig.

Comment: @williclarkam It is correct, but doesn't sound good. I would rather use another tense here: Ich musste das sein lassen.

Comment: @chirlu  vielen Dank, es war sehr hilfreich.

Comment: @Matthias vielen Dank, yeah you are right, it does sound better. Thanks